# Analytic semiconjugacy

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, analyticity, several-complex-variables

Consider the following commutative diagram (semi-conjugacy):
$$ X\;\; \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} \;\;X $$
$${\pi}\downarrow  \;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\downarrow {\pi}$$
$$Y\;\;\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}\;\; Y$$

Assume:

(1) $X$ and $Y$ are real analytic manifolds.

(2) $f$ is a real analytic diffeomorphism.

(3) $\pi$ is a real analytic surjective map.

Question: Is $g$ real analytic? Additional conditions necessary?